# is there a way to convert old Unix Scribe documents?

Tags: conversion, format-conversion

Under Unix there was a typesetting utility called 'Scribe' that would produce typesetting for documents. I have an old file from this that I need to update to some readable format. I can run any Linux flavor, or Mac or Windows, I am just trying to find a way to convert this, even if it means tracking down a copy of the old Scribe source code.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Scribe ( [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribe_%28markup_language%29) ) stopped being available as a commercial product sometime in the mid 1990s. The last known company to sell it is "Cygnet Publishing Technologies", which went apparently closed up shop in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

This website might help you : http://scribenet.com/

Another possible solution -- there is a program called **`s2latex`** which converts Scribe documents to LaTeX:       [s2latex – A scribe to LaTeX converter](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/s2latex.html) .

Comment: Thanks, looks like if I can get that to compile, there may be a solution. Will give it a try.